# Displaying filtered data on Google Form

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, google-forms

Is it possible for me to have a 'choose from a list' question in a Google Form and have two dropdown boxes? Such that, the list items in the second dropdown box will depend on the item chosen in the first dropdown box?

For e.g., in the first dropdown, there could be two choices - fruits and vegetables.

In the second dropdown, the items listed will be 5 fruits or 5 vegetables depending on the choice from first dropdown.

Will be great if you could share any insights!

Thank u!

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: You might have more luck on webapps.stackexchange.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489864/dynamic-selection-options-in-google-apps-scripts-for-forms.