# Dynamic selection options in Google Apps Script for forms

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have [this form](https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1wVvo-rabq-xxXTnWVRDBIwmRCKOA09QAtbNfbRWEG6Y/viewform):

[image: Screen Shot]

If you see List Items - Student Name and Grades are getting populated from a Google Sheet.

What I want to do now is upon selection of List Item Grade, show only those students that belong to that particular grade in the "Select Student" selection...

How can it be done, because form has only two triggers: onOpen and onEdit?

Comment: How do you get the data from an Excel spreadsheet? Are you using a Google spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes data is coming from google spreadsheet via google apps script function we wrote..

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, this type of client side event does not exist in Google Forms. The scripting mechanisms of Google Apps Script are designed for creating forms and other documents, but do not reach very far for client-side functionality.

What I suggest is that you split the form into multiple pages and use the "Go to page based on answer" feature to achieve your desired functionality.

Use `form.addPageBreakItem()` to create pages and use the `item.createChoice(value, PageBreakItem)` to navigate to the correct page.

References:

[Google Apps Script Forms Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/)

[addPageBreakItem](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/form#addPageBreakItem%28%29)

[createChoice](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/forms/multiple-choice-item#createChoice%28String,PageBreakItem%29)

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Thanks to the additional information in follow up comments, the question has been clarified, and boils down to this: *"As a user makes selections in a Google Form, is it possible to customize the options in other questions on that form?"*

A: No. See [Dynamically edit multiple choice options in live Google Form using Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645999/dynamically-edit-multiple-choice-options-in-live-google-form-using-apps-script).

**Original Answer** - this explains how one could change the options presented in a form when the source of those options (a spreadsheet) was edited.

If your data is in a Google Spreadhsheet, an `onEdit` or `onChange` trigger in the source spreadsheet would be able to respond to changes in the name and grade lists.

The `onChange` trigger is "installable", and is able to perform actions that a simple `onEdit` can't, such as modify a form, so it would be the better choice in this case.

In the trigger function, use `FormsApp.openById()` or `FormsApp.openByUrl()`, then update the previous item choices with `item.setChoices()`, reading the values from the spreadsheet just as you did when creating the form.

For bonus marks... instead of blindly overwriting the choices, you could read the existing choices and update them only if changed.

Caveat - on a sheet that changes frequently, or with long lists, this trigger will be computationally expensive. You may find that you run into Google's processing limits.

Comment: But if you see my requirement, i am not changing anything in spreadsheet, i just want to filter student names based on the grades..so do u think the above solution can help?

Comment: Aha, thanks for the clarification. The use of `onChange` in your question, along with reference to populating choices from a spreadsheet, led me down the wrong path. No, you can't change the content of options lists once they are rendered in a browser - See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645999/dynamically-edit-multiple-choice-options-in-live-google-form-using-apps-script/18649165#18649165)