# Create Dynamic Questions on a Google Form

Tags: dynamic, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I have a list of URLs for hundreds of images in a google spreadsheet.  I want to create a google form that dynamically picks 50 of these images, displays them and asks a generic like it / hate it question, then submits this data along with the URL to a spreadsheet.

Is there a way to do this dynamically?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamically edit multiple choice options in live Google Form using Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18645999/dynamically-edit-multiple-choice-options-in-live-google-form-using-apps-script)

Answer (score 2):

AFAIK, you can create form using apps script using a function. But once created it becomes static. Only updating a form would make it as dynamic as possible.

References:

- [Dynamic selection options in Google Apps Script for forms](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20493503/5995040)
- [Dynamically edit multiple choice options in live Google Form using Apps Script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18648306/5995040)
- [Is it possible to show dynamic information in a Google Form based on a previous response?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/96069/is-it-possible-to-show-dynamic-information-in-a-google-form-based-on-a-previous)

## OR

Create a web App using Apps Script.

Hope this helps.