# Google form get email ID when form is loaded for response

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I know there is a getRespondentEmail() which retrieves the email id. But if i'm understanding this correctly, it is only when user submits the form then I'll get information through this. Is there a way to get email id when form is loaded for response. Objective is as follows:

1) Get email id when form is loaded for response

2) access a google sheet and filter data based on this email ID

3) provide the filtered list as a drop down for selecting within the form.

Comment: That would likely be a huge security gap, so I am pretty sure it is not possible. Imagine what could happen if you could have access to the email address of anyone who lands on a url you control?

Comment: Yeah you're right. It is a privacy issue. But is this possible to do what my objective is using any other way? using google forms?

Answer (score -1):

#### Answer:

*This is not possible using Google Forms.*

#### Explanation:

In order to get user information before a user has submitted a form, direct access to the browser session must be retrieved by Google's server *before* form submission. This isn't done.

Until a form has been submitted by the user, therefore giving explicit permission to submit their responses and email address, no information is communicated to Google's servers and as such the email address can not be retrieved before the user submits their answers.

Users are even prompted that their email will be sent with their responses once they submit if the `Collect email addresses` checkbox is ticked in the Form Settings, as this is personal information and they need to decide if they wish to send this information or not:

[image]

Implementing this would be a privacy issue so I can not foresee Google creating this option in the future either.

Comment: I was thinking if this is possible, I create a one question form, user will click on submit, retrieve this email ID, and then use this email ID to create another form with desired options. If this is possible, is there any tutorial you can help me find related to this? Thanks for you reply.

Comment: Check out the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47586640/create-dynamic-questions-on-a-google-form) and go through some of the information they provide. If you're stuck when trying to code this, I think this would be better posed as a new question.