# Cross Check Google Forms and Google Sheets

Tags: validation, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

So I am having a bit of a problem. I am currently making a google form sign up sheet. The only thing is I only want people to have the ability to sign up for certain things if they meet a certain criteria stated in our google sheets document. Currently, I have a spreadsheet email list, of everyone who has been approved. When filling out a google form I want it to block someone from signing up for a spot if they don't meet the approval criteria. Here is an example question.

[image]

If the volunteer is not registered in our google sheets database to be a driver then I want the google forms to block them from choosing that option. I understand script for the most part, I am just unsure how to link the two together. Please let me know if this is possible. If it is, then any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Dynamic selection options in Google Apps Script for forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489864/dynamic-selection-options-in-google-apps-script-for-forms)

Comment: It's not possible with a Google Form.  You could do it with an Apps Script Web App.  You can have a Google Site with an Apps Script Web App embedded into it.