# How can I real-time extract response data from the 'currently being answered' Google form? Before it has been submitted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-forms

I am trying to real-time populate the multiple choice item's options based on the answer to a previous item. To do this, I need to find a way to extract response from a form that hasn't been submitted yet (The very one that is being written right now). Is there any way to do this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic selection options in Google Apps Script for forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489864/dynamic-selection-options-in-google-apps-script-for-forms)

Answer (score 0):

Change event might help
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event

If you need to dynamically change the data displayed, you can use an spread sheet and fetch values with getRange, getValue etc...

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).