# Retrieve Data from Google sheet in Google Form Field based on Google Form Drop down selected value

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-forms

I've two columns in my google sheet Institute PID & Institute Name , Now I am creating google form which has two filed Choose PID ( Drop Down) and Institute Name, I used google script to populate all PID in google form drop-down list from Google Sheet now I want like if user select PID from the drop-down so respected institute Name will fetch from google sheet and show inside the google form field.

I am Sharing code of getting PID from google sheets in Google Form Drop-Down List

```js
//Spreadsheet ID (Get it in URL)
var ssID="1O4wHSFYRkjnuf7AX4A7SnJPjijpvuY8oRYeeE";
//Google Form ID (Get it in URL)
var formID="1E-ELIgOtzVmB6PO8WbNI0NOsV-r3lORZtnlFQOSg";

// "Institutes" is a name of of sheet
var wsData= SpreadsheetApp.openById(ssID).getSheetByName("Institutes");
var form = FormApp.openById(formID);

function main(){

  var labels=wsData.getRange(1, 1,1,wsData.getLastColumn()).getValues()[0];
  labels.forEach(function(label,i){
   var options=wsData.getRange(2,i+1,wsData.
     getLastRow()-1,1).getValues().map(function(o){ return o[0] }).
   filter(function(o){
    return o !== "" });
    
    updateDropdownUsingTitle(label,options)
    
  });

}

function updateDropdownUsingTitle(title,values) {
  
  var items= form.getItems();
  var titles=items.map(function(item){
   return item.getTitle();
  });
  
  var pos=titles.indexOf(title);
  var item=items[pos];
  var itemID=item.getId();
  

  
  updateDropdown(itemID,values);
// Logger.log(titles.indexOf(title));
  
}

function updateDropdown(id,values) {
  
  var item = form.getItemById(id);
  item.asListItem().setChoiceValues(values);

}
```

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Dynamic selection options in Google Apps Script for forms](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20489864/dynamic-selection-options-in-google-apps-script-for-forms)

Comment: AFAIK, you can do this with Google Form. However, you can do the same thing with a WebApps. Share a spreadsheet with some information.

Comment: For the name of the institute, are there several possibilities for a PID?

Comment: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1O4wHSFYRkjnuf7AX4A7SnJPjijpvuY8oRYeeSExy0hE/edit#gid=0

Comment: PID is a unique number for one institute

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe this is possible with current version of Forms. They don't allow custom client side scripting, and don't have appropriate option.

If this is ever changed, I hope someone will post appropriate answer cause I'd like this feature too.

Right now the closest possible workaround is to use [Custom Modal Html Dialog](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/dialogs), however this requires some serious Html/Javascript background to implement these dependant dropdowns manually, so isn't a suitable solution for an average form/sheet user